# Implementation of an objective with unknown number of variables

Tags: c++, cplex

I'm quite new in CPLEX with C++.
I'm trying to model a piecewise-linear objective function (in the LaTex notation):

```
F = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} f_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} K_i * (x_i - x_i^*),
K_i = K_i^1, if x_i < x_i^*; K_i^2, if x_i > x_i^*,
```

that is the sum of values of deviations with weight coefficients. The weight coefficients depend on the sign of the deviation and the index i.

The question is: How to define this kind of the objective function in modelling by row in terms of `Ilo` class or something else?

There are some examples in the internet where an objective function is represented with 2-3 variables, for example,

```
model.add(IloMaximize(env, x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 3 * x[2]));
```

but if I have much more values? And I don't understand how to take into account the weight coefficients in such a representation.

Tnx.

Comment: Are both x_i and x_i^* decision variables?

Comment: If the problem just consists of suming an array in the objective then you can try to create a variable of IloNumExprArg, add your weights and x[i] in the loop and set it as an objective: model.add(IloMaximize(env, yourExpression).

Comment: @zawuza, no, only x_i

Comment: @zawuza, thank you for the idea. But sorry for the question. I declare a `IloNumVarArray` of decision variables, fill it in with their boundaries. And I have a `vector` of `double` constants. How to compare elements of `IloNumVarArray` with standard `double` values and how to perform arithmetical operations?

Comment: The question is closed. IMHO: the documentation to the CPLEX is bad :(